# How to open `shell` or `eshell` in a new window or frame

Tags: shell, eshell

By `M-x eshell` or `M-x shell` Emacs opens a `shell` or an `eshell` in the current window.
How to open this `shell` or `eshell` in a new window?

Comment: The function `eshell` is only 15 lines of actual code (excluding the doc-string).  In my opinion, there is no need to advice or write a fixer function.  Instead, just copy the function `eshell` over the `.emacs` or `init.el` file and call it something new -- e.g., `eshell-other-window` -- change `(pop-to-buffer-same-window buf)` to `(switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)`.  Creating a new function for `shell` can be done much the same way -- it doesn't really matter that it's a few more lines long, because you will only be changing one line of code and changing the name of the function itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple command to open a `shell` in a new window:

```el
(defun shell-other-window ()
  "Open a `shell' in a new window."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (shell)))
    (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer buf))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)))
```

*Edit:* If you want `shell` to open in a new *frame* rather than new *window*, replace `switch-to-buffer-other-window` with `switch-to-buffer-other-frame`.

Comment: And is it possible to make this the default behavior?

Comment: @Name: you could probably adapt this code to write some advice for `shell`.

Answer (score 9):

The canonical way of altering the display behaviour for a buffer is to customize `display-buffer-alist`:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist '(("\\`\\*e?shell" display-buffer-pop-up-window)))
(setq display-buffer-alist '(("\\`\\*e?shell" display-buffer-pop-up-frame)))
```

It's a bit easier with my [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) package though:

```
(setq shackle-rules '(("\\`\\*e?shell" :regexp t :popup t)))
(setq shackle-rules '(("\\`\\*e?shell" :regexp t :frame t)))
```