# emacs opens ESS/R buffer in random window

Tags: window, ess, r

I'm using emacs 26.1 with ESS. Whenever I open a R session with `M-x R` it opens in a random window. However, I would like it to open in the currently selected window.

It seems to be a similar issue as here [emacs opens shells in a random window, how to change this?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34712/emacs-opens-shells-in-a-random-window-how-to-change-this) but the provided solution does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the package [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) for that. After the package is installed the following setting should do what you want

```
(setq shackle-rules '(("*R:?[0-9]?*" :regexp t :same t)))
(shackle-mode 1)
```

If you do not want to use an external package you might be able to adapt this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13585/15268 to your needs.

Note: the regexp `R:?[0-9]?` ensures that the setting applies to all intances of `R`. The buffer with the first instance is called `*R*` and the second is `*R:2*` etc. on my system.